# xorg.conf configuration help on Ubuntu 12.04 ppc

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, xorg, monitor, apple

I did the Xorg -configure or X -configure and I have a xorg.conf file but with errors, so this is something I found out running `ddcprobe`:

```
oem: nouveaufb
memory: 7088kb
edid: 
edid: 1 3
id: 2292
eisa: APP2292
serial: 254c0002
manufacture: 46 2005
input: digital signal.
screensize: 43 27
gamma: 2.200000
dpms: non-RGB, active off, suspend, no standby
ctiming: 248x198@111
dtiming: 1680x1050@59
monitorserial: 2A5463WMUFZ
monitorname: Cinema
```

It seems that Ubuntu recognizes my monitor, but in the xorg.conf file it doesn't show the same info on the monitors, here is what my xorg.conf shows about the monitors, and also why it does show two monitors, I have only one..

```
Section "Monitor"
    Identifier   "Monitor0"
    VendorName   "Monitor Vendor"
    ModelName    "Monitor Model"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
Identifier   "Monitor1"
VendorName   "Monitor Vendor"
ModelName    "Monitor Model"
EndSection
```

and here is what it shows about the screens.

```
Section "Screen"
    Identifier "Screen0"
    Device     "Card0"
    Monitor    "Monitor0"
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     1
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     4
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     8
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     15
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     16
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "Screen1"
    Device     "Card1"
    Monitor    "Monitor1"
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     1
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     4
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     8
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     15
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     16
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

How can I reconfigure? Why my monitor is showing double, and why is the screen double too? some expert in xorg.conf advice needed.

Gus

Answer (score 0):

According to your post you are using opensource driver for nvidia graphics card, I ask you to use the proprietary driver for nvidia

To install latest driver for nvidia cards, run

```
 sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
```

Restart your system

Then open Nvidia X Server Settings Window from Dash or Run the following command

```
 nvidia-settings
```

This window will show you the monitors connected, their resolutions, different modes that can be set for the Display Devices.

You can just do your settings and Save the Configuration.

This will create the xorg.conf and reconfigures them if it is already present in /etc/X11

It works!!

Comment: Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package nvidia-current is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'nvidia-current' has no installation candidate

Comment: looks like it doesn't work for me on Linux PPC